# How to make tag backgrounds reach the edge of the page

Tags: html, css, header

I want to make a header for my page as a bar across the top.  The problem is that it doesn't reach the edges of the page.  It has a white border around it.

Here was my original css code.  It didn't work.

```
header {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

I tried making it bigger but all it did was make it longer so you had to scroll to see all the way down it.  It didn't reach the edge of the page.

I tried some research and saw solutions like these below.  None worked.

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
```

Is there any simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: will you post your page(image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

browsers automatically add a small margin around each page.  To remove this margin, simply use `body {margin: 0;}` to your stylesheet.

Comment: Oh I was adding that to the header.  I see why the solutions I read up on weren't working now.

Comment: Your answer was perfect

Comment: @Zachooz also include padding .. sometimes it could lead to a problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is best to use a reset stylesheet. Browser defaults for margin/padding should be entirely overridden to 0 for ALL elements.

Comment: margin did it for the sides, How would I do it for the top

Comment: I'm sorry I'd have to see your html/css

Answer (score 1):

Put this CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Or else you must probably be having other elements enclosing your header.

Comment: No need to remove margin from `html`

Answer (score 0):

For That Use..

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
</body>
```